# Slice each string-valued element of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have the following array:

```
var arr = ["Toyota", "Hyundai", "Honda", "Mazda"];
```

I want to slice each element backwards, like:

```
var arr = ["Toyota", "Hyundai", "Honda", "Mazda"].slice(-2);
```

so it will return:

```
arr = ["Toyo", "Hyund", "Hon", "Maz"];
```

Is it possible? or is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: And you don't want to iterate through each array member via a for loop and slice each array member by 2 characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `slice` directly, as it has a different meaning with an array and will return you a list of array elements.

```
var arr = ["Toyota", "Hyundai", "Honda", "Mazda"]
arr.slice(0, -2) // returns the elements ["Toyota", "Hyundai"]
```

In order to do the slice on each element, you can use `.map()` (on IE9+):

```
var out = arr.map(function(v) { return v.slice(0, -2) }) 
// or using underscore.js for wider compatibility
var out = _.map(arr, function(v) { return v.slice(0, -2) })
// or using a more modern arrow function
var out = arr.map(v => v.slice(0, -2))
```

Alternatively, you could just use a loop:

```
var i, out = []
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    out.push(arr[i].slice(0, -2))
}
```

or, in more modern syntax:

```
const out = new Array(arr.length)
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    out[i] = arr[i].slice(0, -2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with `Array.protoype.slice()`, no. Try `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
var arr = ["Toyota","Hyundai","Honda","Mazda"].map(s => s.slice(0, -2));

console.log(arr);
```

<sub>See also: `String.prototype.slice()`</sub>