# React Js - create new array with the last two letters in string from previous array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to loop through and array and then get the last two letters from each string and create a new array with them?

my current array is

`myArray = [Qe3,Ke4,Qe5,Je6]`

I would like to end up with this

`newArray = [e3,e4,e5,e6]`

this is for [www.chessonline.app](http://www.chessonline.app)

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far and explain what you're struggling with in particular in your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slice each string-valued element of an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950527/slice-each-string-valued-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `slice`

```js
const newArray = myArray.map(str => str.slice(-2)); // Use map() to apply a function to each element of the array
// The function uses slice() to return the last two characters of each string

console.log(newArray); // ['e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6']
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop over the array and cut first character !

```
 const myArray = ['Qe3','Ke4','Qe5','Je6']
 const newArr = myArray.map((el) => el.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `slice` here:

```js
var myArray = ["Qe3", "Ke4", "Qe5", "Je6"];
var output = myArray.map(x => x.slice(-2));
console.log(output);
```